# MVC View Model Get Child Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, view

I have a main Contact and ContactViewModel . How do I get contact model and update it to the database ?

```
  [HttpPost]  
    public ActionResult EditContact(ContactFormViewModel contactView) {  

    }
```

I was doing like this before I needed ViewModel

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditContact(int id, FormCollection collection) {  
        Contact contact = repository.GetContactById(id);  
                      if (TryUpdateModel(contact, "Contact")) {  
                           repository.Save();  
                           return RedirectToAction("Index");   
 return View(new ContactFormView Model(contact));  
            }   
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit easier when you have a view model (you can forget about `FormCollection` and `TryUpdateModel`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditContact(ContactViewModel contact) 
{  
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model is valid => we can save it to the database
        Contact contact = mapper.Map<ContactViewModel, Contact>(contact);
        repository.Save(contact);  
        return RedirectToAction("Index");   
    }
    // redisplay the form to fix validation errors
    return View(contact);
}
```

where `mapper` converts between the view model and models. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is a great choice for this task.

Comment: I tried this like this  Contact contact = Mapper.Map<Contact, Contact>(contactView.Contact);  repository.Save();  This updates values of Contact object but when I call save its not being saved to the database.I am using LINQ with EF.

Comment: Your `Save` function on the repository should take the instance to save.

Comment: Sorry but as I am very new to EF as well as LINQ I only see  these 3 methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savechanges.aspx. How can I update this cause I will have existing contact in database.

Comment: I tried all possible options.But the entity gets disconnected from object as mentioned http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/24a90f22323a27bc/4d8ae93e0d8c826a?lnk=gst&q=entity+framework#4d8ae93e0d8c826a and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165268/entity-framework-automapper-handling-entity-updates . I am not sure whats correct solution to get this work.

Comment: Not sure but after many tries with Automapper tried as this and worked fine !  
            Contact contact = repository.GetContactById(contactView.Contact.Id);  
           
                if (TryUpdateModel(contact, "Contact")) {  
                    repository.Save();  }